# JPEG to Bitmap to JPEG

Tags: android, file-io, bitmap, javax.imageio

I tried to make a copy of an image file by first decoding the image file to Bitmap and compress it back to JPEG. The copy(~3mbs) is larger than the original file (~2mbs). Is there any way to create an exact copy?

```
        Bitmap origBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        origBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        // this will give me a copy larger than the original image
```

I know I could use FileOutputStream and FileInputStream to create an identical copy. But I want to make some modification to the copy and Android doesn't support Javax.ImageIO.

```
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        File old_file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(old_file); 
        copyStream(input, out);
        // this will give me an exact copy
```

Comment: Maybe is because your original JPEG is compressed, (100 means no compression)

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is a lossy format, which means every time you use the algorithm you're losing some data. It'll look worse every time you do this, even at high quality settings.

Your copy is likely larger because you're using a quality setting of 100. I'd bet that the original file was made with a lower quality setting - usually people use between 70 and 90.

Comment: is there any way to create an exact copy?

Comment: @user3617023 If you're making modifications to the file, it's never going to be an exact copy, as at some point you're going to have to render it down to another re-lossified JPEG.

Comment: +1. In theory, you can get near lossless re-compression of a JPEG by using the exact same tables used in compressing the original. But I don't think the Android Bitmap API supports specifying the tables used for JPEG compression.